# Explanation of a few lines: template matching in python using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching

I need someone to explain to me these four lines of code:

```
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)    
threshhold = 0.70
loc = np.where( res >= threshhold)
for pt in zip(*loc[:: -1]):
```

I kind of know what the first two mean. But the loop part drives me crazy.

- What zip() does in this situation?
- Why did we reverse the list
- what does "*loc" mean? I mean the asteriks
- Whats pt at all?

Rest of the code (the part that matters):

```
while True:
    for i in range(4):
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(imageGrab(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        f = str(files[i])
        template = cv2.imread(f, 0)

        w, h = template.shape[:: -1]

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshhold = 0.70
        loc = np.where( res >= threshhold)
        for pt in zip(*loc[:: -1]):

            x=pt[0]
            y=pt[1]
            center_x = (x + 0.5 * w) + 415
            center_y = (y + 0.5 * h) + 287

            pyautogui.click(center_x , center_y)
            time.sleep(4)
            count = count + 1
            break
```

I put the break at the end because I only want to use the loop once (Do you think there is any better way to do this?)

I will be very thankfull for all the people that answer. You dont have to answer all my questions, if you only know an answer to one then share. Thanks <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)`

matchTemplate calculates for every pixel how well the template matches the image at that location. It returns a 2d array with these values. The method you use is `TM_CCOEFF_NORMED`, the NORMED means the results get normalized, so the values are mapped between 0 and 1. You can display `res`, the best match will be white. This image is taken from docs [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching-in-opencv) where you can find some more info.

[image]

```
threshhold = 0.70
loc = np.where( res >= threshhold)
```

`np.where` returns the indices where the value of `res`/quality of match is greater or equal than the threshold - which is set at 0.70. The indices correspondent to x and y values of the image. The indices are returned as a tuple of 2 arrays - one for the x, one for y.  [Nice examples](https://www.tutorialkart.com/numpy-tutorial/numpy-where/)

`for pt in zip(*loc[:: -1]):`
A few separete thing happen here:
`*loc[:: -1]` An * allows an arbitrary number of arguments. It is used to unpack the `loc`-tuple.   [example](https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/26/unpack-operator-in-python/)
`zip(loc[1],loc[0])` does the same as `zip(*loc[:: -1])`

The reversal of the list seems arbitrary and is not necessary, so long as you account for it in the rest of the code.

`for pt in zip()`
zip() returns an iterable, an object that can be used to loop over. It creates tuples of the input arguments and using `for pt in` it returns these one by one. In this case the input is an array of x-values and an array of y-values, so it will return an (x,y) tuple. The tuple is stored in `pt`.

Try displaying/printing out some of the steps, it will help you understand.

===

if you only want the loop once, I suppose you want the best match. You can use the following:

`min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)`
`max_loc` will hold the x,y of the best match. (the top left corner)